# Snapshotting as Domain Event in Event Sourcing

Tags: event-handling, domain-driven-design, cqrs, snapshot, event-sourcing

I have some pretty constant aggregates in my event sourcing model that will accumulate a large amount of events. I am thinking about using snapshots to optimize the re-hydration of these aggregates. I.E. the aggregates are warehouses.

*My question is whether or not I should produce a specific event for snapshotting, so something like "WarehouseStateSnapshotted"*. In my current prototype, a snapshot state is saved in duplicate code existing in a few command handlers. I feel this is not the right area to be handling it. I would rather dispatch an event for the snapshot to my service bus, and have the event handler handle saving the snapshot state. *This may, however, violate the domain driven pattern of events them self.* Have other's created events for snapshots?

If this is not the right approach, should I at least move my snapshotting logic out of the command handlers and into the aggregate class?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Title and -- [This](https://github.com/rbanks54/microcafe/issues/6#issuecomment-285809608) comment seems to suggest snapshots as domain events is the wrong approach.

**EDIT2:** Simplified Question - Is it appropriate to have repos injected into command handlers?

Comment: Injecting repositories into command handlers would depend on where your command handlers are.  If you mean the method on the aggregate that handles the command then no, do not inject the repository.  I would suggest passing the relevant values into the method.  If, however, the command handler is, say, a service bus message handler (integration layer) then it is absolutely fine since, really, there is no other way :)

Comment: Hmm, ok. My command handlers are messages on a bus using mediatR, where each one calls relevant aggregate handlers to change state. I believe this is the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me attack the easy one first.  The snapshotting logic does not belong in the aggregate.  Whether and when you shapshot is purely a performance concern and so does not belong with business rules.  It helps to draw the line by imagining a server with infinite resources.  If you don’t need to do “the thing” on this amazing machine, “the thing” does not belong in the aggregate.

In the link you posted above I agree with RBanks54 that the snapshot does not belong in the aggregate event stream, for all the reasons he lists.  I think your solution to dispatch an event on the service bus, then handle that event in a different command, is the correct approach.  Handling snapshotting in the context of handling a new event means you cannot snapshot unless a new event is received.  Having a distinct message on the service bus means any process can request a snapshot when appropriate.

Comment: This is a good point that other processes should be able to trigger a snapshot instead of just events. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> My question is whether or not I should produce a specific event for snapshotting, so something like "WarehouseStateSnapshotted".

"It depends".

The reference you should review for snapshoting is [CQRS Documents](https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf), by Greg Young.  It's relatively old 2010, but serves as a simple introduction to snapshotting as a concept.

There's nothing wrong with generating snapshots asynchronously and storing them outside of the event stream.

You can use any sensible trigger for the snapshotting process; you don't necessarily need an event in the stream.  "Snapshot every 100 events" or "Snapshot every 10 minutes" or "Snapshot when the admin clicks the snapshot button" are all viable.

Some domains have a natural cadence to them, where the domain itself might suggest a snapshot -- think "closing the books on the fiscal year".

I'm somewhat skeptical about putting a domain agnostic "make a snapshot" message into the event stream - I don't think it's appropriate to have the aggregate be responsible for snapshot cadence.  It's not broken, but it does feel a bit like overloading the semantics of the event stream with a different concern.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dabbling a bit with event-sourcing but I'm no expert.  I do not particularly like the idea of a separate "*stream*" representing a snapshot.  It isn't much of a stream since it only stores the last snapshot.  In my [Shuttle.Recall](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Recall) project, which is still in its infancy, I store snapshots as normal domain events but they are specifically marked as snapshots and the last snapshot version is stored separately in order to load it and then the events after that version are applied.  I find some advantages to this in that you can add some functionality around snapshots also.

When you are using snapshots as a purely technical performance improvement it may not add much value to your domain.  If a snapshot does not belong in the aggregate/domain then how would one go about hydrating the aggregate from the snapshot?

In some instances a snapshot may be very much part of the domain.  When you look at your monthly bank statement you will not find each and every transaction (event) from the day that you opened up your account.  Instead we have an opening balance (snapshot) with the new transactions (events) for that month.  In this way the "MonthEndProcessed" event may very well be a snapshot.

I also don't *really* buy the argument that should a snapshot contain an error you cannot fix it since an event stream is immutable.  What happens if your event contains an error?  Can you not fix it?  These errors should ideally not make it into a production system but if they do then they should be fixed.  The immutability, to me anyway, relates to the *typical* interaction with the system.  We do not *typically* make changes to an event once it has taken place.

In some instances it may even be beneficial to go back and change some events to a newer version.  These should be kept to a minimum and ideally avoided but perhaps it may be pragmatic in some instances.

But like I said... I'm still learning :)

Comment: I like this answer.

Other domains like story sharing platforms such as Medium.com may need snapshot as part of their domain to support story revisions.